# Veracrypt does not mount to mount directory

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu, veracrypt

When decrypting, one can specify in veracrypt that one want to mount at a specific directory. In Kubuntu 14.04 that worked. Now I installed a new Kubuntu 20.04 and the newly installed veracrypt can decrypt my external harddrive and mount it to `/media/veracrypt1` if I do not specify any specific directory. But when I so specifiy a specific directory (which does exist as an empty directory), it only provides `/dev/mapper/veracrypt1`, but does not mount to any directory. What is going on? How can I fix this?